# How can I control 128 (or more) solenoids?

Tags: multiplexer, solenoid

I need to switch 128 solenoids either on or off individually, several times a second.  I'd like to drive this from either a PC, or an embedded device.

How would you recommend I do this?  Perhaps there is a way I can enable addressing of a group of (8 or 16) solenoids and send a `turn on`, or `turn off` command to them?

Considering what's out there, what is the easiest way to go about this?  What is the best or most preferred way?

I am looking at these solenoid valves that run at about $50 each. Do share information if you know of any cheaper/better ones.  The purpose is to control an indoor waterfall.  It's low-pressure so all the water drips downwards.

http://www.ascovalve.com/Applications/ProductSearch/ProductInfo.aspx?productid=8262H001AC120/60,110/50D&userAction=view

Comment: Need to know how big the solenoids are - voltage/current.

Comment: I'm looking at these that draw 6 to 8W.  If you know of a better/cheaper one that will control the release of water "droplets" do share. $50/per unit is expensive http://www.ascovalve.com/Applications/ProductSearch/ProductInfo.aspx?productid=8262H001AC120/60,110/50D&userAction=view

Comment: Would a sprinkler valve work? Do you need the solenoid to use a 120V coil, or could you use a lower voltage (e.g. 6V, 12V)?

Comment: I can use a lower voltage... but a purely mechanical (non computer controlled) sprinkler valve probably won't cut it.  What would determine my required voltage?

Comment: Sprinkler valves are not that simple. They actually won't work without significant pressure, and they take a while to close as well.

Comment: This may give you a better idea of what I'm working on: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/low-pressure-pulsating-series-of-water-droplets

Comment: I don't think off-the-shelf valves will be fast enough to achieve that unless it's on a large enough scale that small variations in actuation time don't matter. I think you'd need to be looking at more specialised valves specifically designed for fast and consistent on/off times. How to turn them mon/off will likely be the least of your problems.

Comment: here another coil gun?

Comment: Looking at alibaba.com for far-east suppliers, some are offering water solenoid valves for $7 upwards with minimum order qtys of 100. Just a thought. eg: http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/249331163/Water_engineer_solenoid_valve.html

Comment: Thanks @Linker3000 ! - I wonder how those valves fit with @mikeselectricstuff 's comment. What kind of valve would be precise enough (and physically cool enough) to handle a frequent precise change.  From a cost perspective I like your link best!

Comment: "Rapid Sucession" might be misleading. You can't switch solenoids fast enough to put any burden on the speed of the digital interface; the issue is in the hardware costs and design.

Comment: @reemrevnivek - I see.  Perhaps I should open a new question.  Do you mind helping me phrase the question correctly?  I think this forum (electronics) may still be a good fit.  Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: It is a fine forum; electronics is more than just the digital interface.  I've made an edit which should help bring the focus on the interface rather than the speed constraints.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

FTDI USB chip + daisy-chained '595 shift register. Put a separate transistor on each relay.

More detail:

A chain of [74hc595](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MM74HC595.pdf) is described here: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut (Only two are shown, but the concept can be expanded to any number of '595s.)

To drive a the chain, three signals are needed, data, latch, and clock.

You can use an FTDI part in "bitbang" mode to generate three signals from computer control.  To use the FTDI in bitbang mode, use [libftdi](http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/) (You could also use FTDI's official drivers, but libftdi is less hassle in my experience).  A [FT232R](http://ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) has enough pins to do this.  FTDI sells a DIP breakout, and Sparkfun sells some breakouts too.

[image]

Notice you will need 128 2N2222s and 128 330 ohm resistors.  (you can get resistor arrays that might be easier to manage.)

I've drawn the circuit assuming a 12V supply for your relays and no less than 24 ohm coils.  If this is not the case, you might need a sturdier transistor or logic-level MOSFETs.  The 2222 is about as cheap a transistor as you will find, and when you're buying 128 pieces that makes a difference.

I didn't show bypass caps or the exact 232R hookup.  Read the datasheet.

OK, I just saw the solenoid you are trying to control.  2N2222 won't work.  You need to switch 120VAC to the solenoid.  So you can either have a small relay (with 2N2222) to switch the 120V, or use a solid-state relay that can take logic inputs and connect it directly to the '595 output.

OK, here's code to drive this using libftdi.  Pin assigments in the source code.  apt-get install libftdi-dev, then compile like this: "gcc test_595.c -lftdi"

```
/* This program is distributed under the GPL, version 2 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftdi.h>

#define HC595_CT (1) // number of '595 chips

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct ftdi_context ftdic;
    int f,i;

    unsigned char buf[2*8*HC595_CT+1]; // latch pulse, 8*HC595_CT clock pulses

    if ((f=ftdi_init(&ftdic)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ftdi_init failed\n");
        return f;
    }

    f = ftdi_usb_open(&ftdic, 0x0403, 0x6001);

    if (f < 0 && f != -5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open ftdi device: %d (%s)\n", f, ftdi_get_error_string(&ftdic));
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("ftdi open succeeded: %d\n",f);

    // FTDI cable assignments:
#define BIT_DATA (1<<0)  // 1: orange. TXD, "data"
                         // 2: yellow. RXD, unused
#define BIT_CLOCK (1<<2) // 4: green. RTS, "clock"
#define BIT_LATCH (1<<3) // 8: brown. CTS, "latch"

    ftdi_enable_bitbang(&ftdic, BIT_DATA | BIT_CLOCK | BIT_LATCH);

    // set zero
    *buf=0;
    f = ftdi_write_data(&ftdic, buf, 1);    

    unsigned char *b=buf;


    unsigned char data;
    unsigned char state;

    if (argc == 2) {
      data=atof(argv[1]);
    } else {
      data=0x5a;
    }

    printf("sending data %d\n",data);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {   
      state=(data & (128L>>i))?BIT_DATA:0;
      *b++=state;
      state |= BIT_CLOCK;
      *b++=state;
    }
    *b++=BIT_LATCH;

    f = ftdi_write_data(&ftdic, buf, (b-buf));    

    ftdi_disable_bitbang(&ftdic);
    ftdi_usb_close(&ftdic);
    ftdi_deinit(&ftdic);
}
```

And here's a picture of my test setup:

[image]

(I used the [TTL-232R-3V3](http://ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) cable.)

Comment: I'm a bit new to all of this, and I'm self-teaching almost everything.  Can you tell me a little more?  IE specific products, or other tips.  I'm browsing all the FTDI products now looking for the right USB solution.

Comment: I'll sketch the circuit for you later.

Comment: FT245 is probably better than FT232

Comment: What advantage does the 245 give over the 232R?

Comment: That solenoid comes in a wide variety of coil voltages, from 6V to 240V. I would probably pick the 12V coil, such as the 8262G002  12/DC. However, the 120V coil was 6-8W, so something a bit bigger than a 2n2222 might be safer.

Comment: @markrages - FT245 has more IO. Since the bit-bang mode updates all the IO simultaneously, you can run multiple shift-registers in parallel.

Comment: Also, the above schematic needs bypass caps on every IC (0.1uF Ceramic).

Comment: You may event need to go bigger than 0.1uF or have additional caps because the circuit is switching some fairly large currents.

Comment: FT245 can bit-bang 8 IO lines.  FT232R can bit-bang 8 IO lines.  Am I counting wrong?

Comment: +1 - Very nice. Minimal parts and experience required with a reliable a outcome.

Comment: What about using triacs to control the solenoids?

Comment: @Thomas, you would still need an optoisolator to drive the triac.  In other words, you would be rolling your own solid-state relay.  I've done this before and it works, but prepackaged SSRs are really competitive now: http://www.futurlec.com/RelSS.shtml

Comment: To expand on what W5VO said: a 2N2222 will simply not work in this application. Assuming ~ 9 watts for the coil, at 12 volts this implies 750 mA of coil current, and the circuit as shown will not provide that much current as a saturation level. And, while we're looking at things, the 1N4148 flyback diode is WAAAY too small.  Finally, I wonder if you've thought about system requirements. If for some reason you need to turn all your valves on at once, this will require 128 x .75, or 96 amps. That's a pretty good sized 12 volt supply.

Answer (score 4):

Cleaned Schematic with niceties (bypass caps, pin numbers, etc...):

[image]

With the FT245 you could use multiple shorter shift-register chains, since you have more IO.

I didn't draw it like that, but there you are. Anyways, the schematic is done in Altium Designer. If you want the schematic files, I can send them to you, but you need the software to open it.

Comment: This is an improved schematic for markrages' answer, correct? You should probably just put it as an edit there.

Comment: my sample code takes 1+2*8*N FTDI periods for a full shift.  So sixteen 595's would take 257 periods.  The FT232R just uses the async baudrate for clocking in bitbang samples.  So at 115200 baud, a register update is 2.24 msec.

Comment: Ideally, yes, but the USB interface is the slow part. I have a project based around a FT245 in bit-bang mode, and I get ~10 updates per second. Now, I'm doing this in python, so there is almost definitely some interpreter overhead, but I have trouble imagining you's get better than 1000 updates per second, considering each update takes a full USB packet. Unless you're doing something different in C than calling the FT_Write command from the driver, I can't see it being much faster.

Comment: You know you can write more than one byte at a time, right?

Comment: In bit-bang mode? No I didn't realize. Well, nevermind, then. Crap.

Comment: Hahahahaha. Don't I feel clever. Anyways, I've been using these in a application where there are multiple interconnects to the hardware, so the important aspect is propagation time out to the IO pins, not raw throughput. Basically, a hardware write causes the device to respond through another channel, and the response time was all I was looking at.

Comment: Yup. latency is the killer with USB, 1 msec best-case.  I'm not sure what polling interval the FTDI chips request.

Comment: As with markrages circuit, the 2N2222 is not up to the job. Oh sure, the data sheets say absolute max current of 1 A, but that's just too close. Plus, for saturation at a current of ~750 mA, you need 75 mA of base current, and there's no way a 74HC595 will provide that. I approve of the upgraded flyback diode, though.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - If you need more current, either use a darlington, or a FET. I didn't pick the transistor too closely.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason a 7 to 128 decoder wouldn't be appropriate? Using a FTDI chip and serial shift register seems like overkill.

Comment: Yeah. with a pure decoder you can only open 1 valve at a time.

Comment: How expensive are latching relays?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever solution you end up using I would recommend taking a look at the power supply for this beast. You have the potential for really drawing a lot of current by accident (shorting out a transistor due to transient, a clock glitch setting a '1' to many, many outputs, etc.) -- Individual PTCs on each coil protects an individual coil, and I would also suggest either a low-ohm (0.1?) shunt resistor or a hall-effect current sensor which will cut power to the entire driver section if an overload is detected. An op-amp that integrates the overload over time is probably a good hardware trip design, but you can do it in a micro if that's your thing, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would put 16 of [these](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3564) or something similar in series could drive. Not sure how you want to determine on/off but a low-end 8 pin PIC (

Answer (score 0):

Matrix drive.

Mutiplex both your sources and sinks.

Connect the solenoids in arrays. ( rows & columns)

a lot less electronics.

Circuits can be like what's depicted, but you can get by with a lot less if you matrix it.

Comment: This would allow addressing any single solenoid. But the OP wants to control all the solenoids at the same time.

Comment: @markrages would a solenoid notice the difference ?

Comment: Let's see, let's say you have a 9x8 multiplex and drive the solenoid 1/9th of the time.  With a catch diode on the solenoid, current can flow for a while, keeping the solenoid closed.  Assume zero losses, then we want to put the equivalent energy into the solenoid as the solenoid's DC rating.  So drive it with rated voltage * 9.  (to get rated current, di/dt = v/L).  So 24V solenoids would need 216V drivers.  If you stay below the voltage where the coil arcs over this might work.

Comment: LEDs are easily multiplexed because they are open circuit when reverse-biased.  For solenoids, each will need a series resistor for this reason.

Comment: @markrages: If each solenoid had both a series diode to the supply and a reverse-parallel catch diode, multiplexing should be reasonable, though 9:1 seems a bit much.  My inclination, if the application would allow it, would be to use a 4:1 wired multiplex with 12.5% duty cycle for most solenoids; any row which had solenoids that were being newly energized would receive 62.5% duty cycle briefly.  This would require slightly staggering solenoid "grab" operations, but would allow a nice reduction in circuitry.

Comment: Depending upon voltage, it may also be possible to have two rows "grab" with 37.5% duty cycle, or to simply feed all rows 25% duty cycle and see if they could "grab" with that.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative, if you've got a little funds to burn you could always invest in a [Fez Domino](http://www.tinyclr.com/downloads/Component/Broch_FEZ_IO40.pdf) and expand the I2C bus to 320 IOs.

The [Fez Domino](http://www.tinyclr.com/downloads/Component/Broch_FEZ_IO40.pdf) is and embeded C# device, however the IO board mentioned in the PDF uses a standard I2C bus which is common on most uCs.