# SPI Interfacing using Serial Port or USB

Tags: usb, serial, spi, interface

I have a nRF24L01+ module from Nordic Semiconductors. It has **SPI** interface. My laptop has **USB ports** and I have a **Serial Port** (Using a USB-to-Serial_Port adapter). What is the best possible solution to interface with the SPI module?

Comment: USB to SPI: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/usb-to-spi-converter?rq=1

Comment: You can *probably* do this with a Bus-Pirate and some scripting work. It's bring-your-own-code, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a suitable MCU with an SPI port and a USB or serial port, to interface the nRF24L01+ module to the laptop.

Comment: Yes, though there are versions of such sold as (synchronous) serial interface engines, with the presence of an mcu in them not made prominent in their description, and not necessarily even part of the operating signal path.